# Setting selected option in laravel from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I have a problem here, I want to make an edit form, I want the province that appears in the edit form to be the province selected from the database, here my code

```
  <select name="provinsi" id="provinsi" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Pilih Provinsi</option>
                @foreach ($province as $prov)
                <option value="{{$prov->name}}">{{$prov->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

here my controller code

```
public function ShowSantri(Request $request,$id)
    {

        $province = DB::table('provinces')->get();
        $profiles = Profile::find($request->id);

        return view('admin/modal/edit_santri',compact('profiles','province'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
<select name="provinsi" id="provinsi" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Pilih Provinsi</option>
    @foreach ($province as $prov)
         <option value="{{$prov->name}}"
             @if ($profiles['provName'] == $prov->name)
                 selected
             @endif>
             {{$prov->name}}
         </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Just I'm not sure what is name in your `$profiles` for province. But I think that is what you need.

[Here](https://www.hacktension.com/question/VnpFVVdMUzRtR2l0RTBYQUNxMFhiQT09/how-to-define-selected-option-in-laravel-blade-with-old-inputs-) and [here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-set-selected-option-in-dropdown-menuexample.html) are some examples.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use or change this code based on your needs:

```
<option value="{{$prov->name}}" {{ $prov->name == $profiles->prov_id ? "selected" : "" }}>{{$prov->name}}</option>
```

I think the `$prov->name` should be `$prov->id`, if not, you can change `$profiles->prov_id` to `$profiles->prov_name`. It depends on your database structure.